# Creating an SSH tunnel to a port already bound by Docker

Tags: docker, ssh, tunneling

**I want to forward traffic from a docker container on a remote  server to my local development server.**

Basically I have the following setup,

1. I have a local development server on port 3000.
2. I have a remote server which runs a Docker container with nginx that receives incoming web traffic (incoming web traffic is not shown). This part is working already.
3. The incoming web traffic in the container is forwarded to port 7890 in the container.
4. I've published port 7890 on the container to the host on port 7890 with `-p 7890:7890`.
5. Then, I've tried to set up a reverse ssh tunnel from the remote server to the local webserver using `ssh -R 7890:localhost:3000 -N myexampledomain.com`, but then I get the message `Warning: remote port forwarding failed for listen port 7890`, probably because Docker has bound the port 7890 on behalf of the container.

How do I forward traffic the traffic from the Docker container to my local development machine?

I feel like I'm missing some part of the puzzle here. Do you have any suggestions on how to solve this?  I want to continue using Docker for various reasons (I realise this specific example would be made easier by throwing Docker out of the window).

An image detailing the current situation (except for the incoming webtraffic).

[image: tu]

Comment: What traffic is supposed to reach the nginx containers, _vs._ being routed over to your development system?  I think the confusing point in your diagram is that the "container publishes" arrow points the other way – it routes traffic from host port 7890 to the matching port inside the nginx container.  Including a fragment of your nginx config and the relevant `docker run` command might help clarify things.

Answer (score -1):

What you can do is to run the docker container in the `remote server` (the one with `nginx`) in the network mode `host`.

In this way, that container will be in the same network as the host machine which will be able to talk to the port `7890` created by your remote port forwarding without you doing any port mapping like `-p 7890:7890`

**EDIT 1** To make it clear, instead of running the container in the remote host with

```
docker run ... -p 7890:7890 ...
```

run this instead

```
docker run ... --network host ...
```

**EDIT 2** For the benefit of those who are still confused by the question. I will try to elaborate it here:

### What is he trying to achieve

Forward all the requests from a remote server (which is exposed to the Internet) to his development webserver. This is so that when users from all over the Internet access the remote server's IP, the request will be served by the container running in his development environment.

### What has he done so far

1. Create `development webserver` container that listens to port `3000`.
2. Create `nginx` container on `remote server` that listens on port `7890` and map that port from the container to host machine and hence the host machine also binds to port `7890`.
3. From that container, create a remote ssh port forwarding from `development webserver` to `remote server` that forwards all the traffic from port `7890` in `remote server` to port `3000` that the `development webserver` is listening to.

### Problem that he is facing

In `step 3`, when doing remote port forwarding, the command will at the same time trying to bind to port `7890` in `remote server` which is already being used in `step 2`

### What he asks us

Any suggestion to work around this issue as he still wants to use Docker for the solution.

### My suggested solutions

Now, there are 2 solutions for this that will enable him to continue using Docker in this case.

#### First solution as explained in the first 2 paragraphs

This is the simplest and requires the least modification.

1. Since the idea of using nginx is to have a reverse proxy that forward the traffic from the web from 1 port (e.g `80`) to another port i.e `7890` in this case, the `nginx` container just needs to be able to discover the `7890` port on localhost that is created by the remote port forwarding command.
2. Obviously, mapping the port `7890` from local machine to the container is not working and never be the solution. What can be done here is to let the `nginx` container join the `host` [network](https://docs.docker.com/network/host/). In this way, the container will be able to see all the port that the host machine is binding to and vice versa.
3. How this can be done is to run `docker run ... --network host ...` instead of `docker run ... -p 7890:7890 ...` when creating the `nginx` container.
4. If you are using docker-compose, then [network_mode: "host"](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#network_mode) is the way to go.

#### Second solution

This is a bit more advance but it does the job.

1. Install an `ssh server` inside the `nginx` container as explained in the [official guide](https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/running_ssh_service/)
2. Map port `22` of the `nginx` container to an available port in the `remote server` say `30010`. In this way, from the `development webserver`, you will be able to ssh directly into the `nginx` container via port `30010` of the `remote server`.
3. Create an SSH tunnel via the new `30010` port like you normally do e.g. `ssh -R 7890:localhost:3000 -N myexampledomain.com`

Comment: This won't help the problem that both the container and the ssh port-forward are trying to listen on the same host port (and in fact it will make the problem worse by not allowing you to remap the container port).

Comment: My answer is saying that: do NOT map the container port on the remote host (because it's not gonna work), instead, run it in network mode `host`!!!

Comment: The `docker run -p 7890:7890` option implies the container is using the same port number, so this won't help.  It'd be better to try to diagnose the actual issue rather than recommend disabling core parts of Docker.

Comment: Yes and my answer is trying to say that do NOT use `-p 7890:7890` but use `--network host`. Will edit to make it clear!